# cleanest way in git to get new changes to upstream branch to a feature branch

Tags: git, github

When I create a feature branch based off of an upstream branch, the feature branch will retain its branched off commit as the base of the upstream branch, when the upstream branch gets new changes merged in, what is the cleanest way of updating the feature branch's based off commit?  the way I usually do it is

```bash
# checked out feature branch
git pull origin upstream-branch
```

the problem with this method is it creates a new commit in the commit tree and is not very clean, I haven't worked with `rebase` so a comprehensive guide for this use case would be fantastic

a visual of what I want to happen:

before:

```bash
    feature branch  o--o--o--o
                   /
upstream commits  /  new changes
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o
```

after:

```bash
        feature branch    o--o--o--o
                         /
upstream commits        /
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o
```

Comment: `a visual of what I want to happen:` Thats what rebase does. `a comprehensive guide for this use case would be fantastic` I'm pretty sure there are lots of great tutorials online.

Comment: `"I haven't worked with rebase"` - well the good news is that your branch diagrams show that you understand what rebase does, and that you understand when you should use it. You're halfway there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pull -r` auto-rebases your feature branch changes.

Provided there are no conflicts, this should work smoothly.

```bash
# checked out feature branch
git pull -r origin upstream-branch
```

Comment: in order to update the branch on an origin such as github, when attempting to push you will get an error: `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes` you will need to force push to update the github branch `git push --force`, this is super clean I prefer this way